# Set a timer in OCaml or in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, timer, makefile, ocaml

I have coded an analyzer in `OCaml`, the analyzer takes a file as argument and returns an evaluation: `GOOD`, `BAD`, ... I have a `makefile` to launch the analyzer on a set of files one by one.

For some huge files, it takes really long time to analyze. So I would like to set a timer for the analysis: if the analysis time is longer than 3 seconds, the analysis of the current file will be stopped and `TOO LONG` will be returned, and we keep going on with the next file...

Could anyone tell me where to add this timer? around the function in `OCaml` or in `makefile`? And how to do it?

**Edit:** a part of `makefile`:

```
allev:  all
        @n=0; \
        for f in \
        `find . -ipath '*/fetch/evs/*.ev' -exec grep -L -e "' Error" {} \;`; \
        do \
            let "n+=1"; \
            echo "oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" $$n; \
            echo $$f; \
            ./$(BIN) $$f & \
            PID=$$!; \
            (sleep 0.001; kill $$PID) & \
            wait $$PID; \
            echo $$?; \
        done
```

Actually `0.001` second is too short for most of the analysis, so I have got

1. lots of `143`, for the analysis which can not be finished in `0.001` second.
2. `/bin/bash: line 10: 60202 Terminated              ./analyze $f`, I guess this kind of message is printed when the analysis can **not** finish in `0.001` second?
3. `/bin/bash: line 9: kill: (60241) - No such process`, I guess this kind of message is printed when the analysis can finish in `0.001` second?

Literally, the messages still look odd with regard to what happens...

**Edit2:**

I run the analyzer on around 4000 files with a timer of `3` seconds, so most of the analysis can be finished in `3` seconds. They gave me thus lots of messages like `/bin/bash: line 9: kill: (60241) - No such process`.

What is odd is that, after analyzing all the files, the cursor of the terminal doesn't start a new command line. If I press `Ctrl+C`, it will immediately start a new command line. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `Sys.time` tells you how long the current process has been running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in OCaml you might end up using timers and signals from the `Unix` module. Or you can use these same signals and timers from bash if you like.

Here is some bash code to run `<program>` so that it will be killed after `<N>` seconds if it doesn't finish by that time.

```
<program> &
PID=$!
(sleep <N>; kill $PID) &
wait $PID
echo $?
```

Your program should use exit codes less than 126; otherwise they'll conflict with values used by bash. Assuming you follow this convention, a value larger than 128 for `$?` indicates that the program was killed by a signal. (For this specific code you should see the value 143.) A value less than 126 would indicate that your program exited of its own free will.

Signals are tricky to get right, and I've only tested this code a few times. I hope it's useful.

**Update**

Here is a Makefile containing the above code with concrete substitutions for the program and the timeout.

```
testrun: myprogram
    myprogram & \
    PID=$$! ; \
    (sleep 3; kill $$PID) & \
    wait $$PID ; \
    echo $$?
```

If you don't know make(1) well, this might look crazy. The points to watch out for are (A) need to have an actual TAB character at beginning of first command line; (B) need to have `\` at the ENDs of all but last command line (to run all commands in a single shell); (C) need to separate commands with `;` or `&` (because the shell sees this as one long line); (D) need to use `$$` when you want `$` because `$` is special to make. I tested this and it works for me.

If you don't have the appetite to grapple with the syntactic complexities of make and bash, you might want to do this in OCaml.

**Update 2**

I'm not sure what's causing the pause you see at the end. Almost certainly make is waiting for a program it has started up, and the program isn't exiting for some reason. You might run `ps` to see what programs are still running that maybe shouldn't be. If you can reduce to a small amount of code that I (or we) can reproduce, it shouldn't be hard to figure out what's happening and possibly fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Could you please show how to insert that inside `makefile`? I have got an error `/bin/bash: -c: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token '&'`...

Comment: Thanks for the update, I updated my OP following it as well... Could you please confirm the messages I get and its interpretation?

Comment: You said 3 seconds, but now you're using 0.001 second. I wouldn't expect this to work so well. But your interpretation of messages looks OK. You need to be more specific about what you mean by "odd".

Comment: I just added another remark I find odd... I am not sure if it is related to `sleep`... Do you happen to have any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the `Update 2`... I realize that just pressing `Enter` will start a new line (`Ctrl + C` is not necessary), so I add `sleep 3` and `echo "End."` just after the loop in `makefile`, that works...